# VMware horizon client fails in physical machine but works in VM in Ubuntu 20.4 or 20.10

Tags: vmware, 20.10

I have had difficulties using any VMware Horizon client in a physical machine, but it always works in a virtual machine (under Virtual Box) running in the same host where it does not run.

In some machines, it works on bare metal, but usually, those machines have some "better" display adapters, Nvidia or AMD.

Today I updated my HP Elitebook 840-G5 which has Intel Mesa UHD Graphics adapter to 20.4. After update Horizon client stopped working. Just a black screen. So I installed ubuntu 20.10 in a Virtual Box, and everything works nicely.

During installation I get the error:

```
Unable to load gtk: No module named gtk, falling back to console.
```

This does not happen in virtual installation and installer runs in graphic mode.

Any ideas?

Antti

Answer (score 0):

Ok!

Found a partial solution from Reddit threads. Seems, that sometimes multimedia forwarding does not get installed, and then you have knock out H.264 encoding.

"VMware Horizon Multimedia Redirection (MMR)"

Then miraceously everything works..

I do not why this happens, but Now I can use 20.4

Edit on December 30th:

And final solution seems to be:

sudo apt install intel-media-va-driver-non-free

After this driver Blast with H.264 works also....

Problem has never occured with AMD on Nvidia display adapters...

Antti

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently an intel driver bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/intel-media-driver/+bug/2019831
https://github.com/intel/media-driver/issues/1662

The solution is to install intel-media-va-driver-non-free package OR upgrade your Ubuntu version which will likely upgrade the driver to a newer version.